# decltype - "the only context in which a variable defined as a reference is not treated as a synonym for the object to which it refers"?

Tags: c++

I'm reading C++ Primer, 5th Ed., where on p. 71 they first give this code example:

```
const int ci = 0, &cj = ci;
decltype(ci) x = 0;
decltype(cj) y = x;
decltype(cj) z; //error
```

Then they say:

> It is worth noting that `decltype` is the only context in which a variable defined as a reference is not treated as a synonym for the object to which it refers.

What do they mean by this? I don't get it. The `y` there refers to `x`. So what's the catch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe they're trying to say that `decltype(cj)` will not give you the type of the object that `cj` refers to (that is, `const int`) but will give you the type of `cj` itself. So `y` will be `const int&`.

The case to compare this to is when using the name of a reference in an expression. The standard says:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

That is, when using the name of a reference in an expression, it is not the reference that is acted on but the object it refers to. This is what gives a reference type the functionality of an "alias".

Comment: decltype always refers to the underlying type. You'd have to specifically declare your object to be a reference to be given one by the compiler (as in you always receive an lvalue; even if you intend to get an rvalue). But, yes spot on. +1.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thx